# Is it possible to prevent users from uploading small images?

Tags: images, post-thumbnails

Is there a way to prompt an editor whenever they try to upload an image smaller than 350px width? Essentially rejecting any image uploads that are smaller than 350px width?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
   if(!current_user_can('delete_others_posts')){
    /*Handling wp media uloads*/
    add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter','lets_handle_img_width');
    function lets_handle_img_width($file)
    {
        $img = getimagesize($file['tmp_name']);
        $width = $img[0];

        if ($width < 350){
            $file['error'] = "Image is small too small. Get something of width more than 350px.";
        }
        return $file;
    }
}
```

Check official documentation about [wp_handle_upload_prefilter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_handle_upload_prefilter).

Comment: Do you really need the `else` and `return $file` twice?

Comment: Yes It is. Try to remove, you will get long error message :) btw I'm not returning false twice. It's a condition.

Comment: Well, looking at the code logically it shouldn't be needed.  So, I took you advice and tried it on a WP site with the extra code.  Here's what I get:  
**“video-thumbnaiil.jpg” has failed to upload due to an error**  
Image is small too small. Get something of width more than 350px.

Comment: That what needed as per the original question. What is you'r problem I don't understand.

Comment: The code works the way it is and it answers the question.  I just noticed there is unnecessary logic with the else statement.  All that is neede is
   `if ($width < 350){
       $file['error'] = "Image is small too small. Get something of width more than 350px.";`
        return $file;
    }

Comment: Yes, that's better.  I'm sorry for playing code golf, that was not my intent.  The code is more readable (to me) without the `else` and the extra `return`; that is why I commented. I'll upvote your answer.