# Prevent small image sizes from being uploaded

Tags: uploads, media

In a custom meta form, I have a place where the images that should be uploaded should be bigger than 1000px x 500px to show up well on the site.

This page can be edited by my client clients, so we cannot coach/monitor everybody.

Is there a way, while calling the media popup, to prevent the upload/selection of images that are smaller, in size, than a threshold?

Comment: This should be done by client-side, and judging by what you said, they can edit the page... I mean you can check by php AFTER the upload, not before. Anyway would you mind please adding the code you are using for upload to your question?

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/216924) here on WPSE helps you to achieve your goal. *(Btw, I am curious how software and/or human would know which image (and its size) will be uploaded before even one image is selected.)* As mentioned by @Jack Johansson also already.